# Running Linux on VirtualBox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I want to run Ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox (and still keep my Windows OS) and I have been given two choices when I start Linux in Virtual Box `Try` or `Install (as superuser)`.  I don't know which option to choose, I don't want to harm Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VirtualBox creates virtual machines; think of them like computers that run on software (not very accurate but you don't need the details now). These virtual machines are completely isolated from your host operating system (Windows in your case), thus there is no way you can harm your Windows installation.

To your question, “Try” will boot Ubuntu from the iso file you downloaded and you'll be able to get a taste of the operating system, but you'll lose everything you do (in the Ubuntu virtual machine) when you shut down. “Install” will first install Ubuntu in the virtual storage of the virtual machine; thus you'll be able to use it like a normal computer; store files, settings, etc.

Comment: So I should use `install` if I want to use it with Windows 10.  Thanks so much I have been worrying about that for two hours now.  I'm new to this you see and when I saw install I was lost. : )

Comment: Yes, this will make a permanent installation within VirtualBox